# How to use a locally known android phone brand for app development?

Tags: android, android-studio

i know it might be the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490804/can-i-use-any-android-phone-for-application-development) question. i am from the philippines as well but the phone mentioned in that link is a samsung which is an internationally well-known brand and i know that adb supports that brand. what i am planning and really want to buy is [this](http://www.pinoytechnoguide.com/2015/06/cherry-mobile-flare-x.html) locally known phone. it got a really nice specs but i am worrying that i might not be able to use it on app development. i found adb drivers on the net and installed it but i don't know how to use them with android studio. the reason why i want to use a phone for development is because my laptop slows down with i run android studio and the emulator at the same time. if some co-pinoy already know a phone that they already used for app development within the same price range of flare x, please let me know. please guys i really need help on this matter.

Comment: Any phone that can transfer files from and to PC will work. I cannot imagine that this specific phone cannot do that

Comment: If it has android, it will connect to adb, i mostly use osx so i dont have to mess around with drivers but windows has improved a lot in the last years.

Comment: from my experience, not all android phone works with adb. do anyone know of a phone brand named "Firefly". before, i tried to use it for app dev. i turned on its <b>USB Debugging</b> and also the Media Transfer Protocol but when i plug it on my laptop with android studio already searching for devices or let you choose an AVD it doesn't appear on that window. Firefly is also a locally known brand here in the philippines. are you guys using a device for development? what device are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any phone that allows you to enable **USB-Debugging** will be suitable for android development. Most developers try to stick to a phone that has a clean Android base like a Nexus or Moto X, as it rules out any interference with vendor specific changes to Android (like Samsungs TouchWiz).

See [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up) for further information on using a hardware device for development. Google does not recommend any specific device.

Also see [this list](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers) for device vendors providing ADB drivers. If you want to play it safe, stick to these vendors.

[This download page](http://gsmusbdriver.com/cherry-flare-x-v2) suggests that the Google provided driver is suitable for the Cherry Mobile Flare X too.

Comment: hey sir, what is the basis of you answer? do how a site or forum about this stuff?

Comment: I just added some references to my answer.

Comment: do OEM support all android device

Comment: hey sir do you develop in windows, i install the mtp application of windows and the my phone is already recognized by my laptop but not on android studio. what application do i still need to be able to use it on android studio?

Comment: You have to enable USB-Debugging on the phone, this is hidden inside the developer options of Android, which may be hidden by default. Use Google to check how to enable USB-Debugging.

Comment: well, i already enabled that i guess i am still missing something do i need a usb driver for my device?

Comment: You will need the Google USB Driver (according to the link i posted in my answer).

Comment: i already installed the that adb driver but it is still not working. also cherry mobile is not listed in the oem drivers list

Comment: for those persons who down voted this question, can you please give me a decent answer